# Can we use addTagHelper in razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

In an ASP.NET CORE 3.1 MVC project, I added a Custom TagHelper in

```
Views > _ViewImports.cshtml
```

The markup is now working fine in all the views within that folder.

I also scaffolded the `AspNetCore.Identity` pages so in my project I also have

```
Areas > Identity > Pages > _ViewImports.cshtml
```

and then a whole bunch of Razor pages in

```
Areas > Identity > Pages > Account > ...
```

Now whether I add the `TagHelper` to the `_ViewImports.cshtml` or even directly on to any of those Razor pages, the markup just doesn't work.

Do `Razor` pages in `Areas` not work the same with TagHelpers? Can I add `TagHelpers` to `.cshtml` pages in this way or does it only work on `.cshtml` pages in the Views folder?

Comment: It should work, maybe there is a naming typo?

Comment: Could you share example code of how you've set it up?

Answer (score 1):

TagHelper should be absolutely ok with Razor Pages. Just add `@addTagHelper *, <ProjectName>` to your `_ViewImports.cshtml` where `<ProjectName>` is the name of the project where your custom `TagHelper` is defined. The wildcard `*` will make all tag helpers that are defined in  available to all views that inherit from `_ViewImports.cshtml`. If you wish to make only one specific `TagHelper` available to all views that inherit from `_ViewImports.cshtml` add `@addTagHelper <SpecificTagHeler>, <ProjectName>` where `SpecificTagHelper` is the fully qualified name of your tag helper for example `AuthoringTagHelpers.TagHelpers.EmailTagHelper` and `<ProjectName>` is the name of your project or assemby where the `TagHelper` is defined for example `AuthoringTagHelpers` i.e.

```
@addTagHelper AuthoringTagHelpers.TagHelpers.EmailTagHelper, AuthoringTagHelpers
```

or

```
@addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers
```

Answer (score 1):

If add the `addTagHelper` directive in the `Areas > Identity > Pages > _ViewImports.cshtml` page, only the identity razor pages could use the custom tag helper. The view pages in the Views folder can't use the custom tag helper.

To make the `Views` folder's pages to use the custom tag helper, we should add the `addTagHelper` directive in the `Views > _ViewImports.cshtml` page.

To make the Views folder's page and the Identity razor pages to use the custom tag helper, we need to add the `addTagHelper` directive both in the `Areas > Identity > Pages > _ViewImports.cshtml` and `Views > _ViewImports.cshtml`.

Besides, as AntonKovachev said, when we add the `addTagHelper` directive, we should use the project name. For example, my project name is "netcore3", and I created a MyCustomTagHelper in the Taghelpers folder, then, the `addTagHelper` directive  should like this (you can change the project name or the file path to yours):

```
@addTagHelper *, netcore3
```

or

```
@addTagHelper netcore3.TagHelpers.MyCustomTagHelper, netcore3
```

check the following screenshot (the login and register page is the Identity razor page, and the Index page is the View page.):

[image]